# ¿Cómo puedo calcular el MCD de dos o más números sin saber cuántos números son?

Tags: python, random, operador

Trato de hacer que más de dos números aleatorios puedan ser evaluados dentro de una función para realizar el máximo común divisor, pero el problema con el que me encuentro es el no saber si serán más de 2 números a evaluar dentro del programa. He pensado en poner condicionales, pero dudo que sea la manera más óptima de realizarlo.

Mi código:

```
from random import randint, randrange

alm=[]
cantidad=4
for i in range(randint(2,cantidad)):
    alm.append(randint(1,30))
print(alm)

a,b=randrange(2,80,2), randrange(2,80,2)

def mcd(n1,n2):
    if n1<n2:
        i=n1
    else:
        i=n2
    while not (n1 % i == 0 and n2 % i == 0):
        i -= 1
    else:
        return i



print(f'MCD: {a} y {b} es {mcd(a, b)}')
mcd_result=(mcd(a, b))

mcm=((a*b)//(mcd_result))
print('MCM es: '+str(mcm))
```

Justamente aquí tengo el problema `def mcd(n1,n2):` al no poder evaluar si el módulo random elegirá más de 3 números a evaluar. ¿Existe algún método para poder resolver este problema?

Comment: El código que utiliza la librería `random` no está haciendo nada, salvo generar e imprimir una lista de números aleatorios. El código que realmente utiliza la función `mcd()` son los `input` introducidos por el usuario.

Comment: Entiendo esa parte, pero lo he puesto de modo de ejemplo para dar una idea de qué es lo que quiero añadir al código, no sé cómo generar más de 2 números aleatorios para evaluarlos dentro de la función `mcd()`

Comment: Hola en ese caso siguiendo las indicaciones que aparecen en [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) podrías por favor **editar la pregunta** y crear un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Es decir quitar la información y el código que no es relevante para tu pregunta. Así quedará una pregunta más limpia, fácil de entender y será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: @RubialesAlberto Muchas gracias, he corregido el código y la pregunta para ser más acertado. Saludos!

Comment: Lo siento de verdad pero sigo sin entender tu pregunta.  Creas una lista llamada `alm` que no te sirve para nada, puesto que no la vuelves a usar en tu código. Y después te creas las variables `a` y `b` que son las que usas posteriormente y todo funciona correctamente. Lo siento pero no logro entender el problema que tienes, puede que sea culpa mia.

Comment: Me disculpo por no poder expresar correctamente mi duda, me cuesta trabajo planteara y tener una comunicación adecuada. Lo que intento hacer es lo que está en el título, un generador de más de dos números aleatorios que tienen que ser evaluados para posteriormente por medio de usar los divisores de dicho número dar con dos o más números  que coincidan con respectivos números y me arroje el mcd. Si existe otro método completamente distinto al mío, no hay ningún problema en que me lo expliquen. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta es básicamente "como puedo calcular el MCD de dos o más números sin saber cuántos números son".

Para lograrlo solo debes calcular el MCD entre los dos primeros, luego calculas el MCD entre el resultado de los dos primeros con el tercero, a su vez este resultado con el cuarto y así sucesivamente

Un ejemplo podría ser este:

```
from random import randint, randrange
import math

alm=[]
cantidad=4
for i in range(cantidad):
    alm.append(randint(1,30))
print(alm)

a,b=randrange(2,80,2), randrange(2,80,2)

def mcd(n1,n2):
    if n1<n2:
        i=n1
    else:
        i=n2
    while not (n1 % i == 0 and n2 % i == 0):
        i -= 1
    else:
        return i

def mcd_n(n):
    numeros = list(n)
    resultado = mcd(numeros[0], numeros[1])
    if len(numeros) > 2:
        for n in numeros[2:]:
            resultado = mcd(resultado, n)
    return math.fabs(resultado)



print(f'MCD: {a} y {b} es {mcd_n(alm)}')
mcd_result=(mcd_n(alm))

mcm=((a*b)//(mcd_result))
print('MCM es: '+str(mcm))
```

Como veras el problema se resuelve con el uso de una función auxiliar mcd_n que calcula el MCD para n valores, si la cantidad de números es mayor que dos, invoca la función mcd cuantas veces sea necesaria de una forma *recursiva*

Answer (score -1):

Otra manera de realizarlo sería utilizar una lista en donde se almacenen los números aleatorios de la variable definida como `num` en donde puede tomar diferentes rangos. Y con el ciclo **for** se iteren dichos números para posteriormente ser evaluados por una condicional, en donde si esos números aleatorios están en la lista, se omite, de lo contrario, se añaden.

```
numbers = []
for i in range(aleatroio):
    num = randrange(2, 60, 2)
    if num not in numbers:
    numbers.append(num)
```

Se añade una función de mcd para calcular el mcd de dos números:

```
    def mcd(a,b):
        if a<b:
            menor_que=a
        else:
            menor_que=b
        while not (a % menor_que == 0 and b % menor_que == 0):
            menor_que -= 1
        else:
            return menor_que
```

Y como dijo Jacobo Córdoba. Se añade una función auxiliar `mcd_n` que calculo el mcd.

```
    def mcd_n(n):
        numeros = list(n)
        resultado = mcd(numeros[0], numeros[1])
        if len(numeros) > 2:
            for n in numeros[2:]:
                resultado = mcd(resultado, n)
        return math.fabs(resultado)
```

Solo quería corregir eso. Muchas gracias por leer y saludos!